# what is the difference between facter pe_build and facter pe_version?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

what is the difference between facter pe_build and facter pe_version, facter pebuild is returning 2015.3.0 facter peversion is returning 4.3.1 how to get the version correctly in all the puppet master opensource as well as in the enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big difference is, Puppet Enterprise is a software package.

You should be fine to get the information how PE version to map with Puppet opensource version:

```
# Agent Components (On All Nodes)
PE Version  Puppet Agent    Puppet  Facter  Hiera   MCollective Ruby    OpenSSL
2015.3.0    1.3.2   4.3.1   3.1.3   3.0.5   2.8.6   2.1.7   1.0.2d


# Server Components
PE Version  Puppet Server   PuppetDB    r10k    Razor Server    Razor Libs  PostgreSQL  Java    ActiveMQ    Nginx
2015.3.0    2.2.34  3.2.2   2.1.1   1.1.0   1.0.1   9.4.5   1.8.0   5.11.1  1.8.0
```

Refer:

[Overview](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/overview_version_table.html)

Answer (score 2):

`pe_build` is the version code of the overall Puppet PE all-in-one package.  `pe_version` is the version of the Puppet component of that package.  If you find it confusing that these differ then you are not alone.

In any case, both facts are PE-specific, as the name prefix indicates.  If you want the version of the Puppet agent, in a manner that works with both OS and PE, then you should be able to use [`$clientversion`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html#puppet-agent-facts) for that purpose.